# EXCEL INDIRECT both sheet and cell dynamically

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

In excel 2016 on windows, i am trying to reference dynamically to a sheet and a cell.

For example:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$L$2&"'!B33")
```

Where $L$2 has the sheet name and B33 has a numerical value.

However this does not allow me to have the cell B33 dynamic so i can propagate the formula.

I tried:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&$L$2&"'!"&B33)
```

But it throws a #REF!.

Any lead on how to build that formula so that both sheets and cells can be referenced dynamically?

Comment: What does just `="'"&$L$2&"'!"&B33`  return if you put it in a new cell? Just a numerical value in cell `B33` will not resolve to a valid address for `INDIRECT`.

Comment: ="'"&$L$2&"'!"&B33  
this returns the name of the sheet only, not the numerical value i am looking to get

Comment: How are you dragging the formula? Down or Across?

Comment: dragging across

Comment: It's only indirectly referencing the row number, but not the column. It should be something like `=INDIRECT("'"&$L$2&"'!B"&B33)` (if column B should be referenced).

Comment: so you want the next to reference C33 on that sheet? Then D33,E33 and so on?

Comment: yes exactly, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX and INDIRECT to refernce the full row, then when it drags to the right we change the column index:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&$L$2&"'!33:33"),1,COLUMN(B33))
```

Now as is is drug across the column will choose which value to return.